# JRuby on Rails: Adding a folder to the classpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, classpath, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm trying to add an entire folder to the JRuby 1.5 classpath for my Rails app. The [JRuby Wiki](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/FAQs#How_can_I_load_a_ResourceBundle_from_the_Rails_config_directory_?) suggests the following: "... add the config directory to the JRuby classpath in `config/environment.rb`:"

```
$CLASSPATH << "file:///#{File.expand_path(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config'))}/"
```

That doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't matter whether I put that before, after or inside of the `Rails::Initializer.run` block. No matter what, I get:

```
/home/sean/src/sbruby/seo/config/environment.rb:45:NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
/home/sean/apps/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.7/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:2:NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner
/home/sean/apps/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.7/lib/console_with_helpers.rb:5:NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController
```

For example, I'm trying to add a folder under `RAILS_ROOT` called `resources/foobar`, so I added the following to `environment.rb`:

```
$CLASSPATH << "file:///#{File.expand_path(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "resources", "foobar"))}/"
```

Same error.

What is the right way to add a folder to the JRuby classpath with Rails?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Require java first. That's what makes the $CLASSPATH variable live.

```
include Java
$CLASSPATH << "your/folder"
```

In pre-1.0 versions of JRuby, you'd do `require 'java'` instead, but in modern JRuby that silently doesn't work.

Comment: Awesome. That was what I was missing!

Comment: I updated the JRuby wiki as well to reflect that requirement. Thanks again.

Comment: although it is "include Java" rather than "require 'java'" these days (https://blogs.oracle.com/coolstuff/entry/using_java_classes_in_jruby).